# Populate selectOneMenu with data from database after login

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, converters

This project is made with Primefaces 3.5, JSF 2.0, Oracle database.

First a user needs to login. After login it redirects to the "Agenda". This page contains a selectOneMenu which needs to get filled up with data depending on the user that has been logged in.

Login.xhtml

```
<p:inputText style="text-transform: uppercase" value="#{loginBean.username}"   
                            id="username" required="true" label="username" />  
                   <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />  
                   <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"   
                            id="password" required="true" label="password" />
```

my LoginBean.java

```
sets and get my userId which i need to identify my user
also handles my loginrequest.
```

Agenda.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{orResourcesBean.orResource}" converter="resourcesConverter" var="orResource"
                         style="width:250px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Resource" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{orResourcesBean.orResources}" var="orResource" itemLabel="#{orResource.RLname}  #{orResource.RFname}" 
                           itemValue="#{orResource}" />
                <p:column>  
                    #{orResource.RLname}  
                </p:column>
                <p:column>  
                    #{orResource.RFname}  
                </p:column> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

OrResourcesbean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="orResourcesBean")
@SessionScoped
public class OrResourcesBean implements Serializable {

private OrResources orResource;
private List<OrResources> orResources;

public void setOrResource(OrResources orResource)
{
    this.orResource = orResource;
}

public OrResources getOrResource() {
    return orResource;
}

public List<OrResources> getOrResources() {
    orResources = ResourcesConverter.resources;
    return orResources;
}
```

}

ResourcesConverter.java **UPDATED WORKING FUNCTION**

```
public static List<OrResources> resources;
static OrResourcesDao orResourceDao = new OrResourcesDaoImpl();

public Integer uKey;

{
    LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loginBean");
    if (loginBean != null) {
        uKey = loginBean.getUKey();
        if (uKey == null ) {
            resources = null;
        } else {
            resources = orResourceDao.getOrResourcesById(uKey);
        }
    } else {
        resources = null;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            String number = submittedValue;

            for (OrResources orR : resources) {
                if (orR.getRCode().equals(number)) {
                    return orR;
                }
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid resource"));
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(((OrResources) value).getRCode());
    }
}
```

so as you can see in my Agenda.xhtml, the selectOneMenu is filled with all the resources, now i have to fill this with only the resources that are availible to the user that has been logged in. my problem is that i cannot get a parameter from anywhere so i can make my innit method like:

It wont let me put non-static variable in a static (innit) method.

but how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

what i can make out from your problem is you want userId of the User who is trying to login and depending on that userId you want to fire the query 
so, At the time of checking the user for authentication you need to return userId from (DAO to Controller) then set userId within your model
then get the same userId for further processing